# why this configuration of mod_rewrite and .htaccess on localhost on Windows doesn't work?

Tags: windows, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a PHP website, it runs on localhost on an Apache 2.2 and Windows 7.

In my httpd.conf I've enabled mod_rewrite module:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I've a document root located in D:\MyWeb and website I'm working on is in D:\MyWeb\simple_cms

For testing purposes, I've placed .htaccess file in D:\MyWeb\simple_cms and here is it's content:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC]
```

Now, calling for http://127.0.0.1/simple_cms/index.htm should "redirect" to http://127.0.0.1/simple_cms/index.php but it displays "404 Not Found Error" (of course index.php exists there)

In access.log there is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2011:14:16:15 +0200] "GET /simple_cms/index.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 218
```

and inside error.log:

```
[Fri Jul 15 14:19:30 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/MyWeb/simple_cms/index.htm
```

Why this doesn't work? is this regular expression invalid?

Comment: 1) Make sure that .htaccess files in enabled (put `AllowOverride All` in appropriate place); 2) Please enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log.

Comment: `AllowOverride All` - basically, this was the answer. Please, put it as a new answer so I could accept it. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that .htaccess files are enabled (put `AllowOverride All` in appropriate place).
2. If nothing -- please enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart apache after you made changes to `httpd.conf`? It doesn't take new settings in use unless you do that.

Also did you uncomment following line in `httpd.conf` (in case it exists):
`AddModule mod_rewrite.c`

Comment: Yes, I did restart Apache every time after I made some changes to this file. I haven't found this line `AddModule mod_rewrite.c` in my httpd.conf at all

Comment: @Piotr you don't need that line if you use Apache v2 or newer I think.

Comment: @Piotr Did you try this: `RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ $1.php [NC]`

Comment: @Piotr And if you put `D:\MyWeb\simple_cms\index.htm`, you can open it when you call `http://127.0.0.1/simple_cms/index.htm` ?